# Selecting Features Based on Expression on QGIS Attribute Table - Help with Code

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

I want to select features which contain the word 'workings' within the field called Sample_Comments within my CSV file.

I have opened the attribute table and clicked on select features using an expression.

Not sure what to type in for the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Sample_Comments" like '%workings%'
```

Answer (score 0):

See the QGIS documentation about the selection of feature https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection and the use of the expressions https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html